# Why is $1-(y-x)*(1/y)$ equals to $x/y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is it that the result of $1-(y-x)*(1/y)$ is always equals to $x/y$

For example:

$1-(5-50)*(1/5) = 50/5$

$1-(.4-314)*(1/.4) = 314/.4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $1 = y/y$.

> $$1-(y-x)\cdot\frac1y = 1-\frac{y-x}{y}= \underbrace{\frac{y}{y}}_{=1}-\frac{y-x}{y} = \frac{y-(y-x)}{y} = \frac{x}{y}.$$

Answer (score 1):

did you mean $*$ for multiplication? Then
$$ 1 - (y-x) \times \dfrac{1}{y} = 1 - \dfrac{y-x}{y} = 1 - 1 + \dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{x}{y} $$

Answer (score 1):

$1- \frac{y-x}{y}$ = $\frac{y-(y-x)}{y} = \frac{x}y$
provided $y\neq0$

Answer (score 1):

because it simplifies through:

$$1-{y-x\over y}=1-(1-{x\over y})= {x\over y}$$

Answer (score 1):

For fractions with $b, c, \neq 0$
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ad+bc}{bc}$$

Thus
\begin{align}
1-\frac{y-x}{y} &= \frac{y-(y-x)}{y} \\
&= \frac{y-y+x}{y}\\
&=\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}